# Obtaining the IP and MAC of client machines connecting to my ASP.NET MVC application on a server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have just signed up because I need some clarification.  I am an old man but a new graduate of a Systems Analysis college program and am on my first "real" job designing a system for a local company.  Here is the deal.  I am using ASP.NET MVC.  Now, the company has assembly lines in a large manufacturing plant.  Along the lines are stations where workers do a specific job on the line.  The company has paper instructions that explain to the worker step by step how to do the job at their station.  They want all this done electronically now....this is what I 'm doing.

So, when the leader of the assembly line starts their shift, they log into the system by opening up IE and connecting to the application server.  From there, the leader picks a part to "make" on the line.  The system then goes into the repository of instruction documents and retrieves all the documents needed by each station on the line to run the selected part.  The system then needs to prepare the documents according to the station that will use them (ie. station 1 docs, station 2 docs,....etc).  Then, the system needs to automatically open up the IE browser window on the client machine at each station on the line and display the login screen.  The worker then logs onto the station and is presented with the "dashboard" screen with the instruction forms right there in front of him with buttons to navigate through the various docs for his station.

So now, we are wanting to have the system store the IP and Mac addresses of each station machine along each assembly line in a table along with fields that denote the assembly line and station # (ie. so a row in the table would have MAC | IP | ASSEMBLYLINE-ID | STATION-ID).  This table will be populated before hand by admins so that the system knows already what the Mac and IP are for each machine on the floor.  So, when the leader picks a part to run, the system can just check the machine the leader is logged into and get its MAC and IP and then look up in the table what line the machine is on.  Then it can create a document queue for each station on the line, and then when the queues are ready, it can look in the table for the IP's of each machine on the line so that it can open the log on screen on the right machines.

However, it is possible that IP's may change from time to time.  For this reason, we want to make sure we also use MAC addresses to validate the identity of a station machine whenever any communication needs to happen between the system and the clients.  IP's alone just aren't good enough.  Further, we are using all zero clients for this on the stations.

So, if you're still reading, lol.  How can my system on the server, run a getMAC command on a machine that connects to it?

Comment: You can never get the MAC address of someone connected to your website. Socket connections only transmit the IP address. MAC addresses are stored on the ethernet physical layer. Unless there is a direct link between your server and the client machines.

Comment: Would you not be better assigning roles to users so when a user logs in they get to see the document relevant to that role?

Comment: Hey iceman, Thanks for the reply.  By direct link you mean like a cat5 right?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @Fred yeah that would work.   However, workers dont just work on 1 station.  They work at whatevr assembly line they are needed at when they show up for their shift.  Could be Line#1 station A on Monday and Line#6 Station E on Tuesday.  Also, they can work at several stations at once as there are lines here that have only 1 station.  So a worker does sometimes have to man several small 1 station lines at once.

Comment: @iceman OK so using a getMAC remote command would get the MAC of the closest device only?

Comment: @AndrewToole - What you might be able to do, since you are using IE , is create javascript that uses WScript to get the computer name. I can create you a quick example if you want. The only problem with this approach is that it will ONLY work in IE and it might require some specific security settings on the browser.

Comment: @AndrewToole - It would probably return the MAC of your Web Server.  The MAC-address stored in the packet is changed on every hop of a packet's journey. MAC is shorthand for Media Access Control, with media refering to the local communication media. While source and destination IP-Addresses remain the same throughout the journey (and are used for long-distance routing decisions), the source and destination MAC-Addresses just indicate the next hop. Does this make sense?

Comment: @iceman Yeah please anything you can come up with would be great.  We are only using IE here so that's fine.  It doesn't HAVE TO be a MAC address we get, it just has to be unique.  Now will a computer name be valid in the same way for zero clients?  They have no harddrive and just obtain their OS interface through a standard image.

Comment: how secure and fool proof does it have to be?

Comment: @iceman yes that makes perfect sense.  Thank you

Comment: Sounds like you really just need to know which assembly line they're on. Could you do that based off the machine name or just have the user select it from a drop-down list when they log in?

Comment: @Fred foolproof.......ehhh....it's not like anyone is going to hack it or screw with it.  It's just for the floor staff in the plant to use to view the sheets that tell them "Step 1. Don't put your head in the machine.  Step 2. Dont put your arm in the machine. etc"

Comment: @dwillis yes that's exactly all we need to know..  We need some way  for the system to "know" which machine on the floor is associated with which line/station combination.  I recommended a drop down thing but management insists that the workers cannot be trusted even with that.  It must be TOTALLY done automated for them.

Comment: @dwillis The workers may only have access to clicking through the instructions docs and the leader of the line may only enter input up to the point of choosing a part to run.  Nothing else.

Comment: If the machine name is different between images, there must be something you can do to uniquely identify the boxes in a persistent manner, even if it's a simple as a persistent cookie.

Comment: @Dustin Yes, you're right  about the cookie idea.  The problem though is that since they are zero clients, they have no storage for a cookie (or any identifying file at all).  Plus, if they disconnect, then they get a new  image each time they reconnect.  so any file that would have been there before would be lost anyways.

Comment: @AndrewToole - You can configure the DHCP server to always issue the same IP address to a specific MAC address to ensure that the IP addresses will never change.  If, for some reason, you move a machine to a different line then you have to change your table that holds the lookup information.

Comment: @Erik I think I am going to have to do something along those lines.  The more I think about it, the more I am thinking that I will just have it so that the station machines use static IP's.  I will still look into using Computer Name as a backup verifier.

Answer (score 0):

A web server cannot get the MAC address of a client machine. MAC addresses are stored on the physical ethernet layer and are not routed through socket connections. A MAC address stored in a packet is changed on every hop of a packet's journey. MAC is an abbreviation for Media Access Control, with "Media" referring to the local communication media. While source and destination IP-Addresses remain the same throughout the journey (and are used for long-distance routing decisions), the source and destination MAC-Addresses just indicate the next hop.

That being said, you can get the IP address like so:

```
Request.UserHostAddress()
```

However, as you yourself pointed out, this isn't reliable. Especially if the computers are behind a proxy or firewall.

To address your real problem, which is identifying a machine in your assembly line, one method is to get the computer name. You can open a command window and type the command `hostname` and that will return the computer name. It should be unique for each of your machines. If not, you can set it by right clicking on `Computer`. To get this name through javascript, use this code:

```
function GetComputerName()
{
    try
    {
        var network = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Network');
        var computerName = network.computerName;
        return computerName;
    }
    catch (e) { }
    return "";
}
```

Note that this code will only with with Internet Explorer and it may require you to enable special security settings inside the browser.

Comment: Thank you.  That will be very useful.  Is there a way to read the resulting information from the script into an ASP.NET variable so I could use it in the C# code?

Comment: You could use ajax to post the name back to an MVC action.

$.get('@Url.Action("Action","Controller")/'+GetComputerName());

Comment: @B2K Thanks for that.  Can you elaborate a little more on how to do that?  That's Razor syntax you're using, yes? How would I set up the code in the Action body to then store the result of the function?

Comment: That would be so easy to forge and bypass.

Comment: @WiktorZychla - True. However, I'm assuming that the guys working on the factory assembly line probably wouldn't know too much Javascript or MVC.

Comment: @wiktor yeah it may be easy to forge and bypass for you, but no one in the plant knows how to do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is enough for one person to learn how to bypass this, everyone else could follow or even use a premade tool. Someone could even try to sabotage the factory just because of the ease of doing it. What I mean is that you should be extremely careful to not to create unwanted oportunities for people who would want to misuse your system.

Comment: Or you could just fire anyone found tampering with the system.

Comment: public ActionResult Action(string id) {  
      /* id will contain the computer name */  
     return new EmptyResult();
}